# Transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, replication

What is the maximum number of **publishers** one can create on one Database on that same database server itself?

Also, Vice - versa ,

What is the maximum number of **subscribers** one can create on one Database on that same database server itself?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you have the subscribers on the same database server? Why do you need multiple publishers on one database? Perhaps you should explain the problem you are trying to solve.

You only need one publisher per database. One distribution agent can distribute to many subscribers. The distribution agent is usually on a different server to the publisher; subcribers can be located on the same server as the distributor.

The maximum number of subcribers is mainly limited by network bandwidth and the capability of the drives where the Transaction log file of the publisher resides.

Comment: My databases have been deployed seperately... there are different database servers so there will be different publishers and perhaps acc to my settings different distributors too...i needed data of few tables centrally for some other purpose.i solved this problem.Thx fr d other information u gave.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of a "logical" limit to publications/subscriptions. Your limitation will either be linked to licensing (some SQL versions have limited rights for publications) or hardware issues, as noted by [@Mitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298704/transactional-replication#298737)